# Is "evolutionary software architecture" a contradiction?

Tags: design, architecture, agile, architectural-patterns

In my understanding, evolutionary architecture boils down to making architecture easy to modify. Now architecture is often defined as the things that you should get right early because they will be hard to change later.

How does this fit together? Is there any difference between evolutionary architecture and simply minimizing the amount of architecture?

Comment: "architecture is often defined as the things that you should get right early because they will be hard to change later." UNLESS you expect them to change. That makes a huge difference and gives space for future evolution.

Comment: I would agree it is a contradiction in terms, if you define architecture as "everything that is expensive to change later", which is the best definition I have heard to this date. I do not agree with "you should get it right early" though, this definition is the very reason one should postpone architectural decisions as long as possible (in order for them to become as informed as can be).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Neal Ford's keynote on Evolutionary Architecture can be found [here.](http://nealford.com/downloads/Evolutionary_Architecture_Keynote_by_Neal_Ford.pdf)

Paraphrasing:

> Architecture is the decisions
>   that you wish you could get right early
>   in a project, things that people perceive
>   as hard to change.  But what if we built
>   architectures that expect
>   change?
>
> An evolutionary architecture supports
>   incremental, guided change as a first
>   principle across multiple dimensions.

He goes on to describe different architectural scenarios, starting with Big Ball of Mud, layered architectures, microkernels and REST, and culminating in microservices, which he says have *n* dimensions of evolutionary capability (where *n* is the number of distinct microservices).

According to Ford, evolutionary architectures:

- Are [loosely-coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and highly [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)),
- Are composable; components can be assembled to create new architectures,
- Can be changed incrementally, without requiring an architectural overhaul.

You can think of Evolutionary Architecture as a meta-architecture, if you like; an architecture of architectures.  Guidance that dictates design principles that promote casting things in clay instead of stone.

Comment: I like the meta-architecture term. Would you agree that it is a set of principles or techniques that allow you to keep the amount of architecture in the traditional sense small or lightweight?

Comment: I would agree that putting the word "evolutionary" in front of the word "architecture" means that it's not "architecture" in the "traditional" sense.

Comment: In other words: architectures that allow your system to expand in several directions. In Microservices architectures seems evident, in monoliths is not so evident but possible. Modular architectures could be considered Evolutionary too.

Comment: I can more easily think of it as giving a new name to the same old things. Every software methodology I can remember has claimed adaptability to change as one of its qualities. If this is unique, it's primarily in providing even less detail than others about how to achieve that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Most previous methodologies before tried to make an architecture that didn't change, but could be used in face of changing requirements. Evolutionary architecture is about building an environment around the architecture (eg. automated testing and metrics) that allow architecture to change.

Comment: @Euphoric: That doesn't fit with what (for example) Hoare and Dijkstra said when structured programming was new, nor what Booch, Meyer, etc., said when OOP was new, etc. Rather the opposite: most advocated that most of what you'd do was create small pieces that were reusable, so most change was restricted to the architecture. You'd have nice little pieces you could easily reuse in different ways, because the architecture was going to change.

Comment: @JerryCoffin True. But just because previous methodologies didn't deliver on their promises doesn't mean we aren't getting closer. It is okay to be skeptical of new approaches and methodologies. But just because previous methodologies didn't fully deliver doesn't mean this one is the same. Or that we won't be able to learn something new from it.

Comment: @Euphoric: I'd say rather the opposite: structured programming and OOP (for two examples) mostly *did* deliver on their promises. It's harder to say much about this one--I don't expect a lot of details in a key note, but at least offhand, it looks like more hype and less substance than most predecessors.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Did they? I'm too young to know about that. And if you want to know more about Evolutionary Architecture, just read the book.

Comment: @Euphoric: to a large extent, yes, they did. Much of what's routine today would be much more likely to fail using older methods. I've been involved in building a couple of systems that I can hardly imagine trying to do with older methods (though yes, I suppose it would have been possible). As far as reading the book goes, yes, I probably will--but haven't yet.

Comment: Sadly, the more you try to make something easier to change, the harder it is to change, simply because you added more code. We should only make something easy to change if we know it will change.

Comment: Evolutionary architecture smells very badly as a tentative to capitalize on the idea of evolutionary algorithms without understanding what they are. It seems that someone got a liking to a cool term term and tried to push it as something new and awesome when it is actually old, everyday stuff (like when it happened before with dependency injection, DevOps and so many other "new things" on the industry)

Comment: @T.Sar: To be fair, DI is, by any reasonable measure, become a successful idea.  So has DevOps, a term that has allowed practitioners to consolidate and solidify their thinking.

Comment: @RobertHarvey oh, they are very useful. The thing is that they _aren't new_. What people call "DI without frameworks" today is being used for ages already without any special name. Same for DevOps - just new names for old processes.

Comment: @T.Sar Evolutionary architecture and evolutionary algorithms are two completely different things. IMO, "evolutionary" achitecture is not a good name. When reading the book, it felt to me the authors tried really hard to push "evolutionary" terminology into their methodology.

Comment: @Euphoric I'm not saying that they are similar, I'm saying that someone saw the word "evolutionary" in Evolutionary Algorithms, took a liking to it and slapped it over on their methodology without really caring about what it means. Your point is what I meant!

Comment: @T.Sar Possible but unlikely. The whole agile approach is basically evolutionary, meaning that it favors improvements by simple small  steps.

Comment: FWIW I tend to mentally replace “evolutionary” with “incremental” every time I read the word in the context of software @Euphoric

Comment: @FrankPuffer That's just the very old _incremental_ development, as in postulated by the idea of _Software Evolution_ (a very, very old concept - around since before the 80's!). I usually don't bash authors for their work, but this person is trying _very hard_ to create hype around a term to sell old techniques as new. It is like someone writing a C#-clone and calling it a "revolutionary all-new dynamically encapsulated message-based language". "Evolutionary Architecture" is as close as you can get to an IT infomercial. You just need to add the "BUT WAIT! THERE IS MORE!" to it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a contradiction if you are making everything easy to change indiscriminately. If you have to add code to make something "easier to change" (with "easier" poorly defined, as here), then you have made it harder to change, simply because you added code. On the other hand, if you know exactly what will be changing, which is highly unlikely, the additional code should not be viewed as unnecessary complexity.

Making things "easy to change" is probably the main reason much modern software has become so bloated and difficult to change.

Comment: Very true, but not really answering my question.

Comment: Hmm the answer to your question is "Yes".